# Parameterized query in Classic Asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ado

My db access code is like following:

```
set recordset = Server.CReateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set cmd1  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd1.ActiveConnection = Conn //connection object already created
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM lbr_catmaster where catname = ?"
cmd1.CommandType = adCmdText
set prm = cmd1.CreateParameter("@prm", 200, 1,200 , "development")
cmd1.Parameters.Append prm
set recordset = cmd1.Execute
```

But there is no db hit going. Please help with this. I am using sql server 2005.

Thanks.

Comment: Where you say 'connection object already created' - can you post the full code? Are you opening your connection properly? Do you get any error messages, or just an empty recordset? (And are you using On Error Resume Next?)

Comment: @DylanBeattie: I know this because when I simply remove the parameter part and "where clause" from the query, it returns the records. I am also using the sql profiler to check it but no hit is going to the db. No error message is showing.

Comment: Is `adCmdText` defined anywhere?  You don't reference any other ADO constants by name.

Comment: @CheranS: Yes it is defined as Const adCmdText = &H0001

Comment: I think that if it is not even hitting the database, might be it is giving the error but it is being suppressed? But it gives the error when I put the parameter name "@prm" in place of "?" in my query.. Is there any way to know what is going on?

Comment: See the answer i posted for you at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659253/wrong-query-being-generated-when-using-parameterized-query-in-classic-asp/7659445#7659445

Comment: See the answer i posted for you at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659253/wrong-query-being-generated-when-using-parameterized-query-in-classic-asp/7659445#7659445

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my code, this is how I get a recordset from a command:

```
Set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn //connection object already created
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM lbr_catmaster where catname = ?"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandTimeout = 900 

set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@prm", 200, 1, 200, "development")
cmd.Parameters.Append prm

' Execute the query for readonly
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
```

Hope it helps

Comment: There is no need to create an extra object variable `prm`, instead just combine the build of the `Parameter` and the `Append()` to the `Parameters` collection. Like `Call cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@prm", adVarChar, adParamInput, 200))`, then set the value using `cmd.Parameters("@prm").Value = "development"`.

Comment: @Lankymart: these are just samples based on the OP code, the important part here is how to open the recordset

Comment: Followup for anyone reading - "cmd1" on the "set prm..." line should read "cmd". But I can't make an edit less than 6 characters.

Answer (score 2):

I like using Parameters.Refresh, i.e.

```
set recordset = Server.CReateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set cmd1  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd1.ActiveConnection = Conn ' connection object already created
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM lbr_catmaster where catname = ?"
cmd1.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd1.Prepared = True ' only needed if u plan to reuse this command often
cmd1.Parameters.Refresh
cmd1.Parameters(0).Value = "development"
set recordset = cmd1.Execute
```

Comment: Be aware that using `Refresh()` requires an additional call to the server to retrieve the said parameters which doubles every call being made. Would not recommend this in a production environment.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a complex criteria using parameters here is an example I had to create based on my requirements

```
    declare @loc smallint = ? , @dt1 date = ? SET @loc = ISNULL(@loc, 999) 
    SELECT m.* , c.*
    FROM Costs c INNER JOIN MbrData m ON c.SN = m.SN and c.startDT = m.startDT 
    WHERE (m.LocationID = @loc OR @loc = 999) AND (MonthYear = @dt1 OR @dt1 IS NULL) 
    ORDER BY m.LocationID
```

then in your asp

```
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL ' the string above
cmd.CommandType = 1 ' adCmdText
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@loc",2,1) 'adSmallInt=2, adParamInput=1
cmd.Parameters("@loc") = rptlocation ' scrubbed location ID
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@dt1",7,1) 'adDate=7, adParamInput=1
cmd.Parameters("@dt1") = scrubbed formatted date
set rst = cmd.Execute
```

Answer (score 1):

Try leaving off the parameter name:

```
set prm = cmd1.CreateParameter(, 200, 1,200 , "development")
```

Comment: Interesting... In which ways would it make the request functional? I always specify this `name` parameter, without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't referencing your named parameter correctly in your query.

Try replacing:

```
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM lbr_catmaster where catname = ?"
```

with:

```
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM lbr_catmaster where catname = @prm"
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: I also tried this, but then an error occurs which says "Must declare the scalar variable @prm"

Comment: @Dylan: that's the syntax in ADO.net, not in classic ADO

Comment: @Lankymart: using `@prn` it's and ado.net feature

Comment: @EduardoMolteni Actually, both are relevant depending on what `CommandType` is used with the `ADODB.Command` object. `adCmdText` uses `?` and `adCmdStoredProc` uses `@variable` that matches the named parameter using the `CreateParameter()` method.