# Wrong query being generated when using parameterized query in Classic Asp

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado

I am making a database call through the following parametrized query.

```
set recordset = Server.CReateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set cmd1  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_catmaster where (catname =? or catname =?) ORDER BY catname"
cmd1.ActiveConnection = Conn //connection object already created
cmd1.Parameters(0) = "programmer"
cmd1.Parameters(1) = "developer"
set recordset = cmd1.Execute
```

My problem is that when I see the query in the sql server profiler, it is like :

```
"Select catname,catname FROM tbl_catmaster"
```

Please help. I am using sql server 2005.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterized query in Classic Asp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654446/parameterized-query-in-classic-asp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do like this:

```
function commandCreateText(conn, sql)
  dim recordset, cmd1
  set cmd1 = server.createobject("adodb.command")
  set recordset = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")
  set cmd1.activeconnection = conn //which you already have defined
  cmd1.commandtext = sql
  cmd1.commandtype = 1
  set commandCreateText = cmd1
end function

sql = "select * from tbl_catmaster where catname = ? or catname = ? order by catname"
set cmd1 = commandCreateText(conn, sql)
set recordset = cmd1.execute(, array("programmer", "developer"))

if recordset.eof then
  response.write("No records found!")
else
  do until recordset.eof
    response.write("1 record found!")
    recordset.movenext
  loop
end if
```

Comment: This code snippet is giving error as :Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'commandCreateText'

Comment: Because i originally was using it as a function :)
Putting the function in a page which is included in all pages does so only the 3 lines at the bottom of the code snippet should be repeated :)
Code snippet edited...

Comment: hey erizias, now the error gone but the query is not executing... could it be the sql server's version problem?

Comment: i just edited the answer ... Try it out and see if anything is found :)

Comment: hmm... finally... can't tell you how much you have helped me... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create and append the parameters, not sure about the profiler.

```
set prm = cmd1.CreateParameter("@prm", 200, 1,200 , "developer")
cmd1.Parameters.Append prm
```