# How to use session definition in SQL ASP?

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have a session definition on login page named Session("user") and I want to use this session in my sql such as

```
Set insertrec=db.Execute("insert into prgcontrol (vercheck) values ('"&=Session("user")&"' )" )
```

But I could not do anything with this code.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, this is very bad way of talking to database. Never use string concatenation. Learn about parameterized queries. See sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654446/parameterized-query-in-classic-asp).

But anyway, from your code it looks like you have an extra `=` character before `Session`

```
Set insertrec=db.Execute("insert into prgcontrol (vercheck) values ('" & Session("user") & "')" )
```