# How to limit a sql recordset based on a manually entered text field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I am trying to make an html table that will dynamically grab data from a SQL table based on a static field. Right now (thanks to another post on this site) I can get all the results in the table to show up with the following sql and html

**SQL**

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblProductCatalogue INNER JOIN tblProducts ON tblProductCatalogue.ProductID = tblProducts.ProductID WHERE tblProductCatalogue.CustomerID = 1"
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open sql,conn,3,3
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item Number</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>

<% While NOT rs.eof 'loops through records'%>     

  <tr>
    <td ><%= rs("PartNumber)%></td>
    <td><%= rs("DESC")%></td>
    <td><%= rs("DerivedPrice")%></td>
  </tr>

<% rs.MoveNext
Wend 

rs.close
Set rs = Nothing

%>

</table>
```

But now for a slightly different task I would like to be able to have the table only pull up the price and description for partnumbers that I enter in manually into the first cell.

```
<tr>
  <td name="StaticText">PartNumber</td>
  <td><%= rs("Description")%></td>
  <td><%= rs("DerivedPrice")%></td>
</tr>
```

I don't have much experience with any type of programming languages so if you could dumb down your replies a bit for me it would be greatly appreciated. IIS 6 site using classic asp and asp.net with Javascript and SQL Server 2008

Thanks!

Stan

Comment: Might need a bit more explanation. Did you want to type in a part number then at that time bring up the description and price? Or type in one or more part numbers, click submit, and the page will reload with the descriptions and part numbers?

Comment: @John Thanks for the reply. Nothing with any user input, just all entered by me in the .asp file. Trying to make a few pages with odd part numbers that aren't part of any set grouping get dynamic pricing info and preferably be able to get everything just by changing the "part number" field in the html.
 Right now I can sort of accomplish it by changing my SQL to have an 'IN' statement with the part numbers listed but Id like to somehow have the price and description grabbed automatically based on whatever is in the PartNumber is entered as.

Comment: You are not going to be able to use what ever part number is in the table cell HTML to lookup the other details. However, you could have a separate database query for each row of the table (rather than while loop you have in your code above). Not very efficient but might suit your needs. If you want an example of how that is done let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You need a form element called "count" that you post back to the server in an HTML form.

```
<input type="text" name="count" />
```

Then you need to make sure it's a number and not some evil SQL injection code and build up your SQL string:

```
resCount = request("count")
if IsNumeric(resCount)
   sql = "SELECT top " & resCount & " * FROM tblProductCatalogue...."
end if
...
```

In general when taking user input, it's safer to use a parameterized query.

See: [Parameterized query in Classic Asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654446/parameterized-query-in-classic-asp)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I should have explained better.. I am intending on either just entering the fields in html myself or have another employee be able to edit the table to enter in the text rather than get the data from a form field.

Comment: How did you plan to enter the fields into the html?

Comment: @DanBracuk Just manually, there should only be about 5-10 entries per page