# Dynamic SQL in Classic ASP query using JQuery

Tags: jquery, sql, vbscript

I think this *should* be possible but as my experience of JQuery is very limited I'm not sure how to achieve this.

I have a block of code which queries an SQL database, I want to be able to dynamically "change" the query (using WHERE [Printer Make] =) using buttons or a typed in input box.  How would I achieve this?

Here is my current code for a static query:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Printer_Consumables] "
rs.open sql,conn
response.write("<div id='table-scroll'><p>Current Stock Levels</p>")
response.write("<table class='tbl'><tr><th>Printer</th><th>Item</th><th>Stock Level</th></tr>")
i = 0
while not rs.eof
    if rs("Number") = 1 then
        stocklevel = "#0000FF;"
    elseif rs("Number") = 0 then
        stocklevel = "#FF0000;"
    else
        stocklevel = "#008C00;"
    end if
    If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
        response.write("<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;' class='small'>")
    Else
        response.write("<tr style='background: #CCCCCC;' class='small'>")
    End If
    response.write("<td>" & rs("Printer Make") & " " & rs("Printer Model") & "</td><td>" & rs("Type") & "</td><td style='color:" & stocklevel & ";'>" & rs("Number") & "</td></tr>")
    rs.movenext
    i = i + 1
wend
response.write("</table></div>")
rs.close
```

Comment: This looks `classic asp` -- add that tag and you could get some more views.  I don't think you need to use `jquery` for this -- just throw a `form` on the page, add the `input` box and `submit` button, posting the value to the same page.  Then create a variable and set it equal to that value (i.e. `somevariable = request.form("yourinputfieldname")`).  Then you just need to add your `where` criteria -- look up parameterized queries (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654446/parameterized-query-in-classic-asp)

Comment: It sure is classic asp, outdated I know but I'm so used to it now.  I know this is possible with javascript as my predecessor created something but I can't figure out how it works, JQuery is a lot smoother and thought I could use it to dynamically change the query without reloading the page (just reloading a div or frame)

Comment: You can definitely use `jquery` to do that, but you'll need to look up `ajax` as well.  They can work together to do what you're referring to.  Here's the first google post I see that looks pretty thorough: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/98/Ajax-with-Classic-ASP-using-jQuery

Comment: Ah yes - ajax, something I have very little experience with, but I'll go down that route as it may be a better combination to achieve my end result.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

put your current code in a new page naming myfunction.asp and edit it to change sql condition when receives condition like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Printer_Consumables] "

if request("PrinterMake")<>"" then
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Printer_Consumables] where [Printer Make]='"&request("PrinterMake")&"'"
end if

rs.open sql,conn
response.write("<div id='table-scroll'><p>Current Stock Levels</p>")
response.write("<table class='tbl'><tr><th>Printer</th><th>Item</th><th>Stock Level</th></tr>")
i = 0
while not rs.eof
    if rs("Number") = 1 then
        stocklevel = "#0000FF;"
    elseif rs("Number") = 0 then
        stocklevel = "#FF0000;"
    else
        stocklevel = "#008C00;"
    end if
    If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
        response.write("<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;' class='small'>")
    Else
        response.write("<tr style='background: #CCCCCC;' class='small'>")
    End If
    response.write("<td>" & rs("Printer Make") & " " & rs("Printer Model") & "</td><td>" & rs("Type") & "</td><td style='color:" & stocklevel & ";'>" & rs("Number") & "</td></tr>")
    rs.movenext
    i = i + 1
wend
response.write("</table></div>")
rs.close
```

So you need a new page which have a **div** with a certain ID that includes your function file as default with no condition. Then you can reload the content of this div using **Jquery load** where sending condition to myfunction.asp to retrieve new sort of data:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
<!--#include file="myfunction.asp"-->
</div>
<br>
<a onclick="changecondition('SONY')">SONY</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changecondition(brand){
$("#mydiv").load("myfunction.asp",{PrinterMake:brand});
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```