# How to use select with IN operator and value from variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic

I want to select all from the table 'products' where city IN (Varberg,Falkenberg) and if I use the below it works, but if I have the cities in a variable I can´t get it to work? I'm using a mySql database.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM products where city in ('Varberg','Falkenberg')" 
set rs = conn.Execute (sql)
```

So if I use this, it is not working.

```
cities=request.querystring(cities)
```

so that the variable becomes like this

```
cities="Varberg,Falkenberg"

sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE city IN ('"& cities &"')" 
set rs = conn.Execute (sql)
```

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: Tag the programming language also

Comment: How many times is this question going to be asked, there are numerous duplicates already.

Answer (score 1):

The query you generate misses two quotes. The generate query is

```
SELECT * FROM products where city in ('Varberg,Falkenberg')
```

and not

```
SELECT * FROM products where city in ('Varberg','Falkenberg')
```

BTW: Never use parameters provided by the user without validation and proper sanitization.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement created with your variable will be

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE city IN ('Varberg,Falkenberg')
```

which is different than the one you're looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM products where city in ('Varberg','Falkenberg')
```

You need to adjust your code logic to generate the correct list for your variable.  Your variable holds a single value list because of the missing single quotes.  You need to add the quotes so the variable holds a multi-value list.

PS - your code is also wide open to SQL injection.  You should be using a parameterized query.

Comment: Thanks sqluillman, how would a parameterized query look like? I will try to change the logic as you say, thanks.

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson It depends on what language you're using.  Looks like VB.net.  Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i

Comment: Its old asp classic.

Comment: Ok.  Here's a link using classic asp. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654446/parameterized-query-in-classic-asp

Comment: Ok, thanks, will check it out later.