# select statment asp classic with parameter

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

i am working with asp classic with sql server , i want to change my sql statment to prevent injection
my sql statment

this is my sql statment it is run ok

```
%><!--#include file="Config.asp" --><%'  %><!--#include file="Md5.asp"--><%' %>                
<%
                  Dim Encodervalue                                      
                  Dim EncoderResult                                        
                  EncoderValue=Trim(Name)&"_"&Trim(password)
                  EncoderResult=Trim(Name)&"_"&Trim(password)    
                  EncoderResult = Md5(EncoderValue)                       
                  SelectSql="Select * From Users Where User_key='"&EncoderResult&"'"      
              set Rs=ADO.execute (SelectSql)
```

Comment: ' Sanitize the input to allow only alphanumeric characters and underscores
EncoderResult = Replace(EncoderResult, "'", "") ' Remove single quotes

' Construct the SQL query
SelectSql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User_key='" & EncoderResult & "'"
Set Rs = ADO.Execute(SelectSql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parameterized query in Classic Asp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7661608)

Comment: You appear to be using an MD5 hash function on 'name' and 'password'.  That ought to be enough to deal with any injection code in your Request variables in that particular query, but generally speaking @user692942 is correct. Paramaterised queries are the way to go.  If you're concerned about security though I'd recommend using a more modern and robust algorithm than MD5 to encrypt your login details.

Answer (score -1):

If your EncoderResult is not going to be more than 128 characters then you could use the sqlservr built in function QUOTENAME as below ? It'll make a valid SQL Server string by escaping any quotes in the input.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN

```
SelectSql="Select * From Users Where User_key=QUOTENAME("&EncoderResult&",'''')"
```

Comment: thank you , can i prevent user to enter ' in text?

Comment: Hi @abdoZurg, I would assume that would be part of the UI validation. I tried to answer how add check so that the SQL statement does not process an injection